# Simple explanation of terms while running configure command during Tensorflow installation

Tags: tensorflow

I am installing tensorflow from this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/install/install_sources). 
When I run the  `./configure`command, I see following terms

1. XLA JIT
2. GDR
3. VERBS
4. OpenCL

Can somebody explain in simple language, what these terms mean and what are they used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [XLA](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/) stands for 'Accelerated Linear Algebra'. The XLA page states that: 'XLA takes graphs ("computations") [...] and compiles them into machine instructions for various architectures." As far as I understand will this take the computation you define in tensorflow and compile it. Think of producing code in C and then running it through the C compiler for the CPU and load the resulting shared library with the code for the full computation instead of making separate calls from python to compiled functions for each part of your computation. Theano does something like this by default. JIT stands for 'just in time compiler', i.e. the graph is compiled 'on the fly'.
2. [GDR](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/gdr) seems to be support for exchanging data between GPUs on different servers via [GPU direct](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect). GPU direct makes it possible that e.g. the network card which receives data from another server over the network writes directly into the local GPU's memory without going through the CPU or main memory.
3. VERBS refers to the [Infiniband](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InfiniBand) Verbs application programming interface ('library'). Infiniband is a low latency network used in many supercomputers for example. This can be used when you want to run tensorflow on more than one server for communication between them. The Verbs API is to Infiniband what the [Berkeley Socket API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#Socket_API_functions) is to TCP/IP communication (although there are many more communication options and different semantics optimized for performance with Verbs).
4. [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) is a programming language suited for executing parallel computing tasks on CPU and non-CPU devices such as GPUs, with a C like syntax. With respect to C however there are certain restrictions such as no support for recursion etc. One could probably say that OpenCL is to AMD what CUDA is to NVIDIA (although also OpenCL is also used by other companies like ALTERA).

Comment: Actually SYCL, a higher level abstraction of OpenCL, is more like CUDA. SYCL enables developers to use single source, fully featured standard C++. It is the SYCL implementations of ComputeCpp and triSYCL that are used with TensorFlow to enable OpenCL support. E.g https://developer.codeplay.com/computecppce/latest/tensorflow-overview

Comment: GPU Direct allows a CPU to access GPUs in remote systems directly, without the involvement of the remote CPUs, but not direct GPU to remote GPU.  The GPU responds to the third party device (eg Mellanox IB card), but the GPU can't initiate the transfer.  This is the subject of the GPUrdma research project [https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2931091]. I haven't seen this ability announced for CUDA, yet.